# Can sessions save buffers' widths and heights?

Tags: vim, macvim

when I open vim with a session (gvim -S), I always need to readjust the buffers' widths and heights. Is there a way to save the widht and height infos into the session ?

Also, how can I start gvim with gvim's window expanded to the screen's full width (ubuntu)?
Thanks

Comment: Do you still get the problem if you start vim with `gvim -u NONE`, save a session file and then load it with `gvim -u NONE -S session_file`? If not, you probably have a plugin which is interfering with the session-file behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

On my ubuntu machine, widths and heights were screwed up because gvim would open in a non-maximized window.

I solved this by using devilspie which automatically opens gvim in maximized mode.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
set sessionoptions+=resize
```

In your .vimrc

It add the resize options to the sessionpotions (`:help sessionoptions`)